# how to find the value of n in select

Tags: java, jsoup

```
        list2= doc.select("div.idContent > p").get(k);
```

I am having a lot of div's with idcontent as the id in the HTML.
I want to know the value of "k".
I have kept K=0;k<10;k++

than I am seeing Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 9, Size: 9
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
```

using Jsoup how can I find the value of k? and get ride of this exception?

Comment: yes . but my question is using select and all..how can I find the value of N..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doc.select` returns an [`Elements`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) object, which implements [`Collection<Element>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).  This means you can invoke `size()` to determine the range of `k`.

```
Elements elements = doc.select("div.idContent > p");
for (int k = 0; k < elements.size(); k++) {
    Element list2 = elements.get(k);
    // process list2
}
```

However, since [`Collection<Element>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) extends [`Iterable<Element>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), you can use an enhanced for loop instead, which is easier to read:

```
for (Element list2: doc.select("div.idContent > p") {
   // process list2
}
```